# Replicating php hmac sha 256 signing in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to replicate this in javascript.

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', base64_encode(json_encode($commands)), $api_secret);
```

This is to connect to an external api.
In php, the signature generated works fine and gets authenticated.
However, in javascript, i get an invalid signature error from the external api.
This is the code i used for generating it in javascript

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(data))), api_secret).toString()
```

Please note that both of these examples were taken from the API documentation themselves, i'm asking here because i tried to look up other examples but there weren't any, and there aren't any issues reported on this on the git of the api.

Comment: What does `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse()` do?

Comment: It parses the utf8 string and creates an object for it to be encoded to base64